# Copy data from one table onto another using SQL UPDATE statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

```
UPDATE table2 
SET table2.col1 = table1.col1, 
table2.col2 = table1.col2,
    table2.col3 = table2.col3,
...
FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table1.memberid = table2.memberid
```

Please help me to understand how to implement SET clause when there are 9-10 rows, and with common column name SCRIPT_ID so that script can be used again in the future to update the same table.

Here is a snippet from the table:

```
____     _____________   __________________  _____     _     _____
 999     EMS02075SVC     Host Controller     15099     3     60000 
1000     EMS02075SVC     DSM Controller      15099     1     60000 
1001     EMS02075WEB1    Application Server   4447     1     60000
```

Comment: Number of rows is not a problem for SET clause at all. Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i will get back with more details about tables.

Comment: @Kus here is the table details for which i need to create a script, since the data belongs to prod. env , i need to copy the same data to dev env. using the script and the script can be used in future as well.

Comment: 999     EMS02075SVC   Host Controller  15099  3   60000 
1000 EMS02075SVC   DSM Controller   15099  1   60000  1001   EMS02075WEB1  Application Server 4447  1   60000

Comment: You mean an update data from one database to another? Are these two databases running in the same instance?

Comment: @Kaf Yes, one is the production database and other is dev. database. i need to create a replica of the prod. env. on my Dev env. i Think i have almost solve the problem.

Comment: Are those two dbs running in the `same instance of sql server`? If yes then your update is a simple update query. If Not, you need to [link the servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa936675(v=sql.80).aspx) > login > and update.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will work if your source and destination tables are identical and have the same memberids (which I assume are primary keys):

```
UPDATE destination 

SET destination.col1 = source.col1, 
destination.col2 = source.col2,
destination.col3 = source.col3,
...
FROM table1 AS source
JOIN table2 AS destination ON source.memberid = destination.memberid
```

If your source and destination tables are identical, but your source has new rows (records) that the destination lacks, you'll need an selective `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (
    col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    ...
) SELECT col1, col2, col3, ... 
FROM table1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT memberid 
    FROM table2 
    WHERE table2.memberid = table1.memberid)
```

The above will only insert records that are not already in your destination table.  Since you're using SQL Server 2008, you might try playing with the `MERGE` statement which should handle both situations and whatever else you code into it in one set of code.